# Show current product description in custom static block

Tags: product, php, static-block, sql

I already have a working accordion static block on my product page i want to use to display the description.

Currently the description is being shown in tabs above the image which is soon to be disabled/hidden. I need to use a SQL/PHP call to get the product description in plain text and I will use a Div to style it.

Currently I am using this in my static block:

```
{{block type="core/template" name="description" template="custom/description.phtml"}}
```

And that loads this file - which i pulled from my app/design/frontend/default/milano/catalog/product/view/description.phtml:

```
<div id="custom_description">
<?php 
$_description = $this->getProduct()->getDescription();
$_name = $this->getProduct()->getName();
?>
<?php if ($_description): ?>
    <!-- <h2><?php echo $this->__('Details') ?></h2> -->
    <div class="std">
        <?php echo $this->helper('catalog/output')->productAttribute($this->getProduct(), $_description, 'description') ?>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

When I use this, it stops anything loading from that block down. I assume i'm calling too much or too little.

Any help is appreciated! CHEERS!

Answer (score 4):

If you are in product page then you can get  product object of your current product object.
by registry variable

```
   $productObject=Mage::registry('current_product');
$_description = $productObject->getDescription();
```

**current_product registry will give all the value of current product** 
For check this goto

`initProduct` function of class `Mage_Catalog_Helper_Product`

```
 $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
            ->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
            ->load($productId);
......

 Mage::register('current_product', $product);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$productObject=Mage::registry('current_product');
$_description = $productObject->getDescription();
```